# Priority on Singleton EJB With @Schedule

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb

i have one singleton ejb like this :

```
@Singleton(name = "PBEJB")
public class BoardBean implements BoardLocal {

    @Override
    @Schedule(second = "1", minute = "*", hour = "*", dayOfMonth = "*", month = "*", year = "*")
    public void startReadOrders() {
                 doSomthing();
    }
}
```

This bean is very important and must be **run every one minute** on start of minute(second 1).
Is it guarantee that in any situation the startReadOrders() method run on scheduled time?

Answer (score 1):

From [EJB3 In Action 2nd Edition](https://www.manning.com/books/ejb-3-in-action-second-edition) *7.1.1 Timer Service features* page 197:

> Although the Timer Service is robust and timers will survive server restarts/failures, the Timer Service doesn’t
>   support real-time scheduling. This means that you shouldn’t use the EJB scheduling
>   capabilities for situations where you must respond to real-world events within a measureable timeframe. A measurable timeframe is a period of time in which you
>   absolutely must process a request or provide a response.

The author also specifies:

> The EJB Timer Service is
>   applicable in situations that aren’t mission-critical (where something bad happens if
>   you’re late by a nanosecond). For example, sending out an email broadcast at midnight
>   with bid statuses is a good fit for the Timer Service. Using the Timer Service to monitor
>   the pilot tubes on an airplane and calculate engine thrust would be a bad solution.